# How to make the Levi-Civita express the value from the package xAct?

Tags: xact

I try to use the package xAct to compute the 1-form field from 3-form field as shown in the picture below. However, the value of Levi-Civita or epsilong does not express. How could I solve this?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.